# How to scale Kubernetes on Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to scale up my Kubernetes cluster that I started on Azure. I have several deployments running on it, and one of them is causing most of the CPU power. So, I decided to scale it up. However, when I increase the number of nodes on Azure, most of the load is still on the three nodes I started with, while the others have little to none.

Can anyone help me with this? Am I missing something?

[image: Node loads]

Comment: How does the deployment look like, what amount of replicas did you specify?

Comment: @PeterBons for the deployment that I am concerned about, I have 5 replicas right now. I have been trying to scale up and down, but that deployment doesn't show up in the other nodes.

Comment: check node selectors\taints

Comment: Do you try to delete some of the replicas? If you do this, does the new replicas create in other nodes by the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something which AKS manages on its own (if we don't provide any custom scheduling rules), if you want to place the load to other nodes, you can do this.

```
kubectl cordon AKS_AGENTPOOL_NODE_NAME
```

Try checking then

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep  AKS_AGENTPOOL_NODE_NAME
```

Try killing few of them and you can see the load will get transferred to other nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. I have used this to distribute the load equally.

Answer (score 0):

Pods don't get rescheduled until they terminate and are replaced. You can slowly kill some of your pods and they should move over to the new nodes.

Comment: when I do that, it only spread the pods in the first 3 nodes I had when I created the cluster, not the newly created ones.

Comment: Hmm, check for any node selectors, taints, or pod affinity settings?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be weird. do one thing to move the work load off from those three nodes.
Apply a taint on those nodes such that pod doesnt get scheduled. use the below command

```
kubectl taint nodes <node-name> key=value:NoSchedule
```

delete the pod from the tainted node. The pod should be scheduled on other nodes.